# How does the Wigner-Eckart theorem rule Multipole Expansion?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, multipole-expansion

I am wondering why a spin-S particle have only the term up to $k=2S$ in his multipole expansion ?

It [seems](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/119802/77326) that the Wigner-Eckart theorem shows the relation between spin and multipole expansion but I can't see why !

Thank you